# how to label lines when they are from different columns in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataframe is like

```
Date Y1 Y2
1   1   1
2   2   1
3   2   4
4   5   4
5   2   3
...
```

I use the following piece to plot Y1 and Y2

```
ggplot(aes(x = date))+
    geom_line(aes(y = Y1), color = "darkred", size = 1) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = Y2), color = "steelblue", size = 1) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 2, linetype= 'dashed')+
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          legend.position = 'bottom',
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14))
```

But the legend option did not work and the figure has no legend.
How can I add the legend or label to the lines including the vertical one?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `pivot_longer` and `scale_color_manual` to specify legend and color values for plot elements.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
dates <- tibble(Date = 1:5, Y1 = year(today()) - 1:5, Y2 = year(today()) - 4:8)

dates %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Date) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = name)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 2, color = "vline"), linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "lines", 
                     values = c(Y1 = "darkred", Y2 = "steelblue", vline = "orange"))
```

[image]

To specify labels for each of the legend entries, use the `breaks`/`values`/`labels` arguments to `scale_color_manual`:

```r
... %>%
scale_color_manual(name = "lines", 
                     breaks = c("Y1", "Y2", "vline"),
                     labels = c("year1", "year2", "important"),
                     values = c("darkred", "steelblue", "orange"))
```

[image]

Comment: Can I also define the labels in the legend for Y1 and Y2?